# Proteincalculator with algebra

Tags: c, double, calculator

Im trying to make this protein-calculator (in C language) to work but it doesn't work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double proteinhalt[20];
    double proteinmangdtot[20];
    double kottfiskmengdtot;
    printf("Enter proteinhalt / 100 gram: ");
    fgets(proteinhalt, 20, stdin);
    printf("Enter proteinmangd att konsumera idag (gram): ");
    fgets(proteinmangdtot, 20, stdin);
    kottfiskmengdtot = ((double)proteinmangdtot/(double)proteinhalt)*100;
    printf("Du behöver %f gram.", kottfiskmengdtot);
}
```

The error is:

```
Line 13   error: pointer value used where a floating-point was expected
```

What is wrong?

Edit: In english:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double proteinpercentage[20];
    double proteinamounttot[20];
    double meatfishamounttot;
    printf("Enter proteinpercentage / 100 gram: ");
    fgets(proteinpercentage, 20, stdin);
    printf("Enter protein amount to consume today (gram): ");
    fgets(proteinamounttot, 20, stdin);
    meatfishamounttot = ((double)proteinamounttot/(double)proteinpercentage)*100;
    printf("You need %f gram.", meatfishamounttot);
}
```

Comment: What is it that your program is doing? What's the expected output? Could you please try to reformat the code in English?

Comment: You seem to expect that `fgets()` will input to `double proteinhalt[20];`. That should be `char proteinhalt[20];` and then you must extract some floating point value, ditto with `proteinmangdtot`.

Comment: Why char when it is a number? Its just meatfishamounttot = (proteinamounttot/proteinpercentage)*100 when thinking algebra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors.

1. fgets, expects a character array as argument, but you specify an array of doubles
2. at the assignment of meatfishamounttot, you cast an array of doubles to a double

**Solution** (simplified, no error checking):

```
char str[20];
double proteinpercentage;
double proteinamounttot;
double meatfishamounttot;

// read at most 20 characters from stdin
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
// convert the string to a double
proteinpercentage = strtod(str, NULL);

fgets(str, 20, stdin);
proteinamounttot = strtod(str, NULL);

meatfishamounttot = (proteinamounttot / proteinpercentage) * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how the program should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

int main()
{

char str[20];
double proteinpercentage;
double proteinamounttot;
double meatfishamounttot;

printf("Enter proteinpercentage / 100 gram: ");
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
proteinpercentage = strtod(str, NULL);
printf("Enter protein amount to consume today (gram): ");
fgets(str, 20, stdin);
proteinamounttot = strtod(str, NULL);

meatfishamounttot = (proteinamounttot / proteinpercentage) * 100;
printf("You need %f grams.", meatfishamounttot);

}
```